# angularjs routing issue: cannot get routing work with ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to make ng-view work but ng-view doesn't show anything. I have angular.js 1.2x and also angular-route.js. Spent a good time to make it work but can't figure out.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',
                    {
                        templateUrl: "app.html"
                    })
                    .when('/pizza', {
                        templateUrl: "app.html"
                    }).otherwise({
                        template: "This doesn't exist!"
                    })
        });

        app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {

            $scope.model = {
                message: "This is my app!!!"
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Hello There {{2+2}}</h1>
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view page, it only shows Hi There 4. This means that the page is displayed and also the expression {{2+2}} is working. I do have all the html files on the root.

Any idea guys?????????
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create a controller to assign to your routes, eg:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "app.html",
    controller: 'RootCtrl',
});
```

Then setup a basic controller to associate with app.html.

Comment: Nope. controllers are not required.

Comment: As in you don't require them, or you haven't tried?

Answer (score 0):

got it working but still not sure what made it work. I didn't change anything in code. Just started NodeJs server and navigated thru port from nodejs config. When that worked, I stopped the server and viewed without it and it still worked. So not sure what made it work but its working. I"ll update this when I figure out main reason.

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Fiured out why it wasn't working. It seems like I had a conflict in between angular.js and angular-route.js. Ah garra be careful when you have multiple versions on the machine. Once I overrode them with same versions, it started working. So no issue with code. It was just different versions of js files.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs works on SPA, so you need to separate index page and then other page , this is working on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZ2mdmx946qaUJEcEHxC?p=preview)

your code look like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/firstPage', {
            templateUrl: 'firstPage.html'
            //controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
        })
        .when('/secondPage', {
            templateUrl: 'secondPage.html'
            //controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/index'
        });
  }]);
```